# Android - print full exception backtrace to log

Tags: android

I have a try/catch block that throws an exception  and I would like to see information about the exception in the Android device log.

I read the log of the mobile device with this command from my development computer:

```
/home/dan/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/adb shell logcat
```

I tried this first:

```
try {
    // code buggy code
} catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but that doesn't print anything to the log. That's a pity because it would have helped a lot.

The best I have achieved is:

```
try {
    // code buggy code
} catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.e("MYAPP", "exception: " + e.getMessage());             
    Log.e("MYAPP", "exception: " + e.toString());
}
```

Better than nothing but not very satisfying.

Do you know how to print the full backtrace to the log?

Thanks.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

```
try {
    // code that might throw an exception
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
}
```

#### More Explicitly with Further Info

(Since this is the oldest question about this.)

The three-argument Android log methods will print the stack trace for an `Exception` that is provided as the third parameter.  For example

```
Log.d(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr)
```

where `tr` is the Exception.

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841232/java-android-how-to-print-out-a-full-stack-trace#comment9560980_7841300) those Log methods "use the `getStackTraceString()` method ... behind the scenes" to do that.

Comment: In addition, My style: Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);

Comment: Beware using e.getMessage() - getMessage() may return null, depending upon the type of exception that has been thrown, which would in itself cause an exception as null is not supported as a message parameter in the Log methods. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage%28%29)

Comment: Besides, it makes more sense to describe what kind of code caused this exception in the second parameter. The message is already included in the output anyway.

Comment: What @Unique says is very important. It is better to use Log as mentioned in the answer since it already prints the stack trace

Comment: `Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);`

In this MYAPP is for what? Please explain

Comment: @SignoffTeamz You could just read the documentation. It's an identifier that shows up the log that makes it easier for you to filter the log and see which app (and which part of it) wrote the message. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#e(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Throwable)

Answer (score 56):

This helper function also works nice since *Exception* is also a *Throwable*.

```
    try{
        //bugtastic code here
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         Log.e(TAG, "Exception: "+Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
```

Comment: It is a string used to specify the app and location. Any string will do there.

Answer (score 8):

```
catch (Exception e) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  PrintStream stream = new PrintStream( baos );
  e.printStackTrace(stream);
  stream.flush();
  Log.e("MYAPP", new String( baos.toByteArray() );
}
```

Or... ya know... what EboMike said.

Answer (score 4):

```
public String getStackTrace(Exception e){
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
  e.printStackTrace(pw);
  return sw.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

e.printStackTrace() prints it to me. I don't think you're running the logcat correctly. Don't run it in a shell, just run

`/home/dan/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/adb logcat`

Answer (score 1):

The standard output and error output are directed to /dev/null by default so it is all lost. If you want to log this output then you need to follow the instructions "Viewing stdout and stderr" shown [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat)

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
            ...
} catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to print out stack trace without exception, you can create it by following command

```
(new Throwable()).printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 0):

**KOTLIN SOLUTION:**

You can make use of the helper function `getStackTraceString()` belonging to the `android.util.Log` class to print the entire error message on console.

**Example:**

```
try { 
 
   // your code here
    
} catch (e: Exception) {

     Log.e("TAG", "Exception occurred, stack trace: " + e.getStackTraceString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin extension. Returns the detailed description of this throwable with its stack trace.

```
e.stackTraceToString()
```