# How to increase no of lines(log level) in Logcat

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, logcat, android-logcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java / Android - How to print out a full stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841232/java-android-how-to-print-out-a-full-stack-trace)

i am working on an android app.
Sometimes it stops working and show force close error.

when i view the logcat it shows 4 to 5 lines then says 15 more/ 11 more. i cannot reach to line where that exception occured. Is there any way to increase view full stack trace.

Please Help I am stuck.
Thanks.

If i have not explained properly please someone edit the question.

EDIT:
Answer to question is

[Java / Android - How to print out a full stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841232/java-android-how-to-print-out-a-full-stack-trace)

Comment: click on the maximize button on the top-left of the logcat window.

Comment: I have tried that but there are not more lines in logcat. Last lines just says ".....15 more"

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using Windows/Eclipse...

Window -> Prefernces -> Android -> LogCat -> Maximum number of logcat messages to buffer

Set it to a value that makes it more usable to you.

Comment: Does it get better if you increase it?  You are probably hitting that limit with all the different info sent ot LogCat from even the simplest app.

Comment: I have checked. there are atmost 100 lines.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841232/java-android-how-to-print-out-a-full-stack-trace
this answer did the trick. thanks for your response.

Comment: This is wrong. Buffer size setting does not affect the number of lines from stack trace that are printed. It only affects how far back you can scroll in the log. Default is 5000 messages.