# Stack trace as String

Tags: java, exception

How do I get full exception message in Java?

I am creating a Java Application. If there is a runtime exception, a `JDialog` with a `JTextArea` will pop up. I tried to make a runtime exception in my application, but the text area showing the exception message looks like this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.Application
```

However, I want my text area to show something like:

[image]

Here is some part of my code surrounded by the `try` and `catch`:

```
String ex = e.toString();
this.addText(ex);
```

I've tried to use `e.getLocalizedMessage()` and `e.getMessage()`, but neither of these work.

Comment: Check the updated answer that I have provided. You can get trace converted to string format for you to display.

Comment: use `ExceptionObject.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Just the stack trace to string part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/how-can-i-convert-a-stack-trace-to-a-string

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You need to call the `Throwable#printStackTrace(PrintWriter);`

```
try{

}catch(Exception ex){
    String message = getStackTrace(ex);
}

public static String getStackTrace(final Throwable throwable) {
     final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
     final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw, true);
     throwable.printStackTrace(pw);
     return sw.getBuffer().toString();
}
```

You can also use commons-lang-2.2.jar Apache Commons Lang library which provides this functionality:

```
public static String getStackTrace(Throwable throwable)
Gets the stack trace from a Throwable as a String.
```

[ExceptionUtils#getStackTrace()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getStackTrace%28java.lang.Throwable%29)

Comment: Awesome! Helped me in a InputStream error in Android :)

Answer (score 6):

if you are not using any logger(Log4j or oracle logger api) then you can use the below statement to print the full exception message

```
try{
       // statement which you want to monitor 

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace()
    // OR System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());
    // OR System.err.println(e);
    // OR System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    // OR System.err.println(e.getCause());
}
```

if you are using the Logger API then use the below statement

```
try{

         // statement which you want to monitor 

}catch(Exception e){
  log.error(e,e); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To get the stack trace into a string you can use these lines:

```
    CharArrayWriter cw = new CharArrayWriter();
    PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(cw);
    e.printStackTrace(w);
    w.close();
    String trace = cw.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static String getStackMsg(Throwable e) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(e.toString()).append("\n");
    StackTraceElement[] stackArray = e.getStackTrace();

    for(int i = 0; i < stackArray.length; ++i) {
        StackTraceElement element = stackArray[i];
        sb.append(element.toString() + "\n");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `e.printStackTrace()`, it will print trace for your exception with lines mentioned

Answer (score 1):

This is the full exception message.

If you want more information try e.printStackTrace()

then you will get excatly what you see on the picture you postet

Answer (score 1):

[e.printStackTrace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) will give the full stack trace