# Control exception output format

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, exception

I am trying to control how the error is going to be displayed.

I am trying to do something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22271986/10538678 but on **global level** (for every exception thrown). I tried this example described in this question, but i have no idea how to implement this globally

Instead of:

```
Exception in thread "threadName" Name of Exception : Description
... ...... ..  // Call Stack
```

For example i want error to display:

```
<Error>
    <ErrorCode>customErrorCode</ErrorCode>
    <ErorMsg>Description</ErorMsg>
    <ErrorClass>className</ErrorClass>
    <ErrorThread>threadName</ErrorThread>
</Error>
```

EDIT: I have multiple dependencies which use exception handling and i cannot modify them.

Comment: Do you have a `main` method ? If it's the case, the question you linked still works. Just wrap the instructions in `main` with the try catch clause

Comment: I have multiple dependencies which throw errors... I would like to catch every error and change output to xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to add [ControllerAdvice](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring). In your case it would be something like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
  extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<String> handleException(Exception e) {
        String bodyOfResponse = "This should be application specific";
        return new ResponseEntiy<String>(bodyOfResponse )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a DefaultExceptionHandler with `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();`
as the name tells you, it handels uncaught Exception thrown with `throw` but not printed stack trace!

But if somewhere in youre code you used `try{}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}` you cant do enything to change the way it is presented

Comment: Hmm that is interesting.. In code, i have calls like theese: void functionName() throws Exception { ... }