# Format String in Json Response

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to send stack trace in api response if Spring Boot is running in profiles other than production so that it will be easy to debug issues.

I already tried \r and \n but they are printed as is.
What I want is new line should be displayed instead of \n.

I have tried both Apache Commons Library and my custom converter to get stack trace in String format.

```
//Using Apache Commons library 
private String getStackTrace(Throwable ex) {
        return ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex);
}

//Custom
    private String getCustomStackTrace(Throwable throwable) {
        //add the class name and any message passed to constructor
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.append(throwable.toString());
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        //add each element of the stack trace
        for (StackTraceElement element : throwable.getStackTrace()){
          result.append(element);
          result.append(NL);
        }
        return result.toString();
      }
```

output Json I am getting in Postman :

```
{
    "apiStackTrace": "java.lang.NullPointerException at xxx.xxx.Controller.getxxxxx(ABC.java:56)\n\t at xxx.xxx.xxxController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fd2ed167.invoke(<generated>)\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)"
    "status": "failure",

}
```

Expected Json

```
{
"apiStackTrace": "
java.lang.NullPointerException at xxx.xxx.Controller.getxxxxx(ABC.java:56) 
 xxx.xxx.xxxController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fd2ed167.invoke(<generated> 
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)"

"status": "failure",

}
```

If you see what I am getting in apiStackTrace is having \n\t characters printed in response which is making it unreadable.

What I want is apiStackTrace should have explicit new lines to make it more readable.

So question is how to achieve this.

PS:
This change is for DEV and QA profile only, so in postman response we want to see stacktrace so that we can avoid opening log file again and again.

Comment: Any use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271099/convert-exception-to-json

Comment: tried.. still getting \n in response instead of actual new line.

Comment: Your _"expected JSON"_ isn't valid JSON. How are you displaying the response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiline strings in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json)

Comment: @Phil, there is some confidential data in json, so i have given only a section of it.

Comment: @Phil, seems its not possible. Do you have any idea about same?