# File upload not working android

Tags: java, android, file-upload

I have the following file upload function:

```
    public void uploadFile(Context context, File file) {
        String urlServer = "https://u-database.000webhostapp.com/recieve_file.php";
        if(file.isFile() && file.exists()) {
            String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
            try {
                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                DataOutputStream dos = null;
                String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                String twoHyphens = "--";
                String boundary = "*****";
                int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                byte[] buffer;
                int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
                Toast toastw = Toast.makeText(context, "Inside TRY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toastw.show();

                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                URL url = new URL(urlServer);

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("textLog", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"textLog\";filename=\""+fileName+"\""+lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Uploading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

                if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                    file.delete();
                    Toast toasto = Toast.makeText(context, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toasto.show();
                }

                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Malformed URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Each time it is executed, a toast appears stating Inside TRY and then another appears stating "Exception".**

I have been debugging a lot and any kind of help would be really appreciated :)

**UPDATE**

When I did `e.toString` and printed it out to a toast, I got: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: Well it would tell you more if you checked what `ex` has to offer (such as `printStackTrace` or something similar)

Comment: Well, @ItamarGreen thanks for looking, it's generally part of a BroadCastReciver so I can't debug it in AVD as it doesnot have any activity. So basically its hopeless. Do you know other ways to get stacktraces?

Comment: Well, to log the exception, you can refer to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841232/java-android-how-to-print-out-a-full-stack-trace

Comment: @ItamarGreen where? I dont see links there

Comment: what do you mean? there's a link in the comment.

Comment: @ItamarGreen thanks for that, but I can't get the log values for I can't run this application by pressing the debug button in Android Studio as it doesnot have any activity. :)

Comment: @Abhishek perhaps you can take a screen shot of the exception (the toast).

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani it's a background service, e.printStackTrace() does not do anything, and I have put a toast there to debug, by which I am knowing that I am generating exceptions. The toast displays only "Exception"

Comment: Can't you edit the code and printout the toString() of the exception?

Comment: Trying that @DoronYakovlev-Golani

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani its a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception, I also edited my question. Really thanks for giving that tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple then. You should run your network calls on a background thread. You need to extend `AsyncTask` and move your code into it. Something like:

```
private class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... p){
         // Call upload file code here
      }
}
```

Comment: Can it be a inner Class?

Comment: Sure. You can look at this tutorial for a lot more explanations and examples: https://androidkennel.org/android-networking-tutorial-with-asynctask/ .

Comment: Missing return statement @DoronYakovlev-Golani

Comment: Solved it by adding return null, testing it now. but I really cant display toasts there.

Comment: This is just a pseudo-code skeleton (I didn't compile it)... you have to fill in the details.