# Android studio cannot getApplicationContext() to aws

Tags: javascript, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am following the aws guidelines but get that error for `getApplicationContext()`.

```
package com.example.wcyv3.stylish;

import android.content.Context;

import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;

public class ManagerClass {
  public CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCredentials() {
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    getApplicationContext(),// Context
                    "ap-southeast-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", // Identity pool ID

    );

    return credentialsProvider;

  }
}
```

Comment: provide the stacktrace please, check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841232/java-android-how-to-print-out-a-full-stack-trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you don't have `getApplicationContext()` method in your class which is belong to Activity, Fragment, Application, etc. To solve the problem, you can pass the context via the **constructor** or you can set the method as **static** then passing the context as the *parameter*.

Via constructor:

```
public class ManagerClass {

  private Context context;

  public ManagerClass(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  public CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCredentials() {
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                context,
                "ap-southeast-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", // Identity pool ID

       );

    return credentialsProvider;
  }
}
```

Or via parameter of static method:

```
public class ManagerClass {

  public static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCredentials(Context context) {
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                context,
                "ap-southeast-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", // Identity pool ID

       );

    return credentialsProvider;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use this method inside your activity class or use a parameter of type `Context` in the method.

```
public CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCredentials(Context context){
    return new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider (context, "ap-southeast-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" // Identity pool ID
        );
```