# Android SAX parser fails for HTML tag <a>

Tags: android, html, html-parsing, saxparser, saxparseexception

The SAX parser fails for the following HTML data

```
<article class="episode">
<img class="lazy-loaded" src="./index_files/timthumb(3).php" data-src="https://example.com/test.jpg&amp;w=390&amp;h=210&amp;zc=1">
</img>
<a href="abc"></a>
</article>
```

but works well when i remove the  tag as shown below:

```
<article class="episode">
<img class="lazy-loaded" src="./index_files/timthumb(3).php" data-src="https://example.com/test.jpg&amp;w=390&amp;h=210&amp;zc=1">
</img>
</article>
```

Following is the DefaultHandler written for parsing

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.barnowlanims.starlight.MovieListItem;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SaxXmlMovieListHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private final String FILENAME="SaxXmlMovieListHandler";
    private List<MovieListItem> mMovieListItems;
    private String tempVal;
    private MovieListItem movieListItem;
    private boolean isArticleStarted=false, isSectionStarted=false;

    public SaxXmlMovieListHandler() {
        mMovieListItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<MovieListItem> getMovieListItems() {
        return mMovieListItems;
    }

    // Event Handlers
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                             Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // reset
        tempVal="";
       Log.e(FILENAME, "startElement: qName:"+qName+", localName:"+localName+", uri"+uri);
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("article") && attributes.getValue("class").equalsIgnoreCase("episode")) {

            // create a new instance of MovieListItem
            movieListItem = new MovieListItem();
            isArticleStarted = true;

        }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("section") || attributes.getValue("class").contains("cardBox")) {
            movieListItem = new MovieListItem();
            isSectionStarted = true;

        }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("img")) { 

                if(isArticleStarted) {
                    movieListItem.setThumbnail(attributes.getValue("data-src"));
                }

        }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {

            if(isArticleStarted) {
                movieListItem.setUri(attributes.getValue("href"));

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

        Log.e(FILENAME, "endElement: qName:"+qName+", localName:"+localName+", uri"+uri);
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("article")) {

            if(isArticleStarted){
                mMovieListItems.add(movieListItem);
                isArticleStarted = false;
            }
            // add it to the list
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("section")) {

            if(isSectionStarted){

                mMovieListItems.add(movieListItem);
                isSectionStarted = false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        super.endDocument();
        Log.e(FILENAME, "qName:"+"endDocument");
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        super.startDocument();
        Log.e(FILENAME, "qName:"+"startDocument");
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        super.fatalError(e);
        Log.e(FILENAME, "qName:"+e.getStackTrace());
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        super.error(e);
        Log.e(FILENAME, "qName:"+e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

A snippet of error log when running with  tag

```
E/SaxXmlMovieListHandler: qName:startDocument
E/SaxXmlMovieListHandler: startElement: qName:article, localName:article, uri
E/SaxXmlMovieListHandler: startElement: qName:img, localName:img, uri
E/SaxXmlMovieListHandler: endElement: qName:img, localName:img, uri
E/SaxXmlMovieListHandler: startElement: qName:a, localName:a, uri
D/SaxXmlParser: parse() failed[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@425b5ab0
E/BlankFragment: Parser returned null
```

I would really appreciate some help

Comment: Can you get your code to emit a full stack trace? It would help a lot to see that. Otherwise it’s hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code, but one guess is that `movieListItem.setUri(…)` is failing for some reason. Short of a stack trace, maybe you could could add some `Log.e(…)` calls before and after that `movieListItem.setUri(…)` call to see if it’s actually calling that and returning from it successfully.

Comment: To get your code to emit a stack trace, you can use a try-catch like `try {
    // code that might throw an exception
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
}` or `try {
    ...
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.d("Some tag", Log.getStackTraceString(e.getCause().getCause()));
}` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341363/android-print-full-exception-backtrace-to-log/4341391#4341391 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841232/java-android-how-to-print-out-a-full-stack-trace/7841306#7841306 etc