# Uploading image to Firebase Storage gives exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Following [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-storage-example/) tutorial to Store Image path to *Firebase Storage*

Here is my code:

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
String STORAGE_PATH_UPLOADS = "Profile Pictures/" + UID + "/" + imgID;
StorageReference sRef = storageReference.child(STORAGE_PATH_UPLOADS + "." + "jpg");

sRef.putFile(imgPath)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Exception:

```
StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
```

I searched on this but didn't get any solution

Comment: The exception you show misses the most important information, which is likely in the inner exception. Instead of showing a toast, log the entire exception with `Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341363/android-print-full-exception-backtrace-to-log

Comment: as per link you have an image view,So are you see image when you try to upload image.because i got this error when image was null when trying to upload.

so please first check image is null or not

Comment: @UttamMeerwal image is not null, it gets displayed in the ImageView.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your comment. So it is `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider`

Comment: The file you upload has to be on the local file system. It seems like Android doesn't recognize `imgPath` as a local file. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+%22No+content+provider%22