Unable to read QR code using ZXing in Kotlin on an Andorid 12 tablet
I'm new to Kotlin and I need to make an application that reads QR codes, I did this using the following code:
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy
import com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader
import com.google.zxing.Reader
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer

class QRCodeAnalyzer(private val qrCodeListener: (String) -> Unit) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    private val reader: Reader = MultiFormatReader()

    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        val buffer = imageProxy.planes[0].buffer
        val data = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
        buffer.get(data)
        val source = com.google.zxing.PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(
            data,
            imageProxy.width,
            imageProxy.height,
            0,
            0,
            imageProxy.width,
            imageProxy.height,
            false
        )
        val bitmap = BinaryBitmap(HybridBinarizer(source))
        try {
            val result = reader.decode(bitmap)
            qrCodeListener.invoke(result.text)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("============================ UnknownException: ${e.message} ==========================")
        } finally {
            imageProxy.close()
        }
    }
}


My project has a minimum version of Android SDK 21 and I am using the following dependencies:
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.6.0")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.3")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.3")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.3")
    implementation("com.google.zxing:core:3.5.3")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

This code reads the QR code perfectly in tests on the Android Studio simulator and on an 8.7-inch Android 14 tablet.
However, when trying to run it on a 10-inch Android 12 tablet, it cannot read the QR code and returns no error
Logcat is too big to put in the question, so I put them on github. The links are below.
8.7 inch tablet logcat: https://github.com/igorskeff/erros/blob/main/8.7%20inch%20logs
10 inch tablet logcat: https://github.com/igorskeff/erros/blob/main/10%20inch%20logs
In both cases the same QR code is used and I tried varying the distance to check that there were no focus problems.
If try catch is removed, the error that logcat gives on the 10 inch tablet is as follows:
2024-05-07 16:04:09.897 13229-13305 AndroidRuntime          com.example.cardapionamesa2          E  FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.cardapionamesa2, PID: 13229
                                                                                                    java.lang.Error: com.google.zxing.NotFoundException
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1173)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
                                                                                                    Caused by: com.google.zxing.NotFoundException

The tablet on which the error occurs is the following: Samsung SM-T505, Android 12, API 31
The used tablet that is working correctly is the following: Samsung SM-T225, Android 14, API 34
What can be done to fix this?

Add to your post any logs / error messages from logcat that would be helpful. Specifically differences between the good device and bad device when scanning.

I added the logs to the question, I had to host them on github due to the size. I don't have any error messages, the QR code is just not read.

Sorry didn't notice you were capturing exceptions. remove and let the app crash with stack trace. Add the crash stack to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64805201/295004

Ok, I removed the try catch and added the error I received in the response. I tested with e.getStackTraceString() and got the same error.


What are the specs of each tablet (make/model). 2)I would double check all of your libraries, a few look old like androidx.camera:camera-camera2 and should be on recent versions, see: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera


Firstly, thank you for your attention. The tablet that is causing the problem is the following: Samsung SM-T505, Android 12, API 31. The other tablet is the following: Samsung SM-T225, Android 14, API 34.
Additionally, I updated my camera-related libraries, but the error still remains. I added the tablet models and updated the libraries I'm using in the question.

Definitely odd. Assuming you are using the main camera rather than selfie, and the same QR code (on paper or screen?), and the QR code is black and white not some other color, I would definitely try a few other barcodes/QR codes to see if its just a particular one or for all barcodes on 10-inch tablet. I would also see if any hints to ZXing help.

I tested both cameras, and tested the same QR code (black and white) on both tablets.
I also tested other QR codes with different correction levels, but the 10-inch tablet continued to be unable to read them.
I tested some hits to ZXing help, but unfortunately I didn't get any results.
I also tested switching from ZXing to com.google.mlkit.vision, but no changes again.
I started to suspect that perhaps the device had some problem or specificity.
However, I tested the QR code reading native to the device's camera and it was able to read the QR code.

If the OEM camera app works but yours doesn't, it may be a bad unit device problem. Alternately Samsung did something so that the device isn't returning the expect image. If Open Camera from F-Droid doesn't reveal any issues with taking normal pics, all I can suggest is to save/examine the image before sending it to ZXing.  Perhaps the bitmap format is wrong or something with endian-ness returned to CameraX  but it would be best to have someone with the same Samsung tablet SM-T505 confirm behavior.

Ok, thank you very much, I'll try to get another tablet of the same model and test it.
